# Does Keras use class_weights in a custom loss function?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Simple question, cannot find anywhere:

An example Custom Loss Function:

```
def player_loss(self, y_true, y_pred): 
     return K.categorical_crossentropy(y_true,y_pred)
```

Will this loss function use the `class_weights` if provided to the `fit_gen` method when called automatically?  Or if you use a custom loss function, you must write a loss function which uses the weights manually?